# Cognos Mashup Service CORS error

Tags: web, web-applications, cors, xmlhttprequest, cognos

So I am trying to get the Cognos Mashup Service to work from the examples given here: https://www.ibm.com/communities/analytics/cognos-analytics-blog/how-to-use-ibm-10-2-2-cognos-mashup-service-cms-samples-in-ibm-cognos-analytics-11/

**The application actually works perfectly when running in Eclipse using the internal browser.** However, when I change the default eclipse browser from internal to external like Firefox or Chrome, I get a CORS Access error when connecting to Cognos 11:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://placeholder/ibmcognos/bi/v1/disp/rds/pagedReportData/report/i72BCF4B83AFE430F9A7F4721DF093FAB?fmt=HTMLFragment&selection=List1&rowLimit=2. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)

From what I understand, I need to add the following to my server config file:

```
<Location />
order allow,deny
allow from all
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</Location>
```

However, this just caused an infinite loop of 404 errors. **So what am I doing wrong, and why does the internal eclipse browser work?** This is my simple web app html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Generic Authentication Sample</title>
<script>

var myNameSpace=null;
var myUserName=null;
var myPassword=null;

try {
  var objXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } catch (e) {
    try {
        alert('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
      var objXHR = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
    } catch (e) {
      try {
          alert('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')
        var objXHR = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
      } catch (e) {
        alert('XMLHttpRequest not supported'); }
      }
  }      

 function doReport()
 {

    myNameSpace=document.getElementById("nameSpace").value;
    myUserName=document.getElementById("userName").value;
    myPassword=document.getElementById("password").value;
    var myReportID=document.getElementById("storeID").value;

    var myFrag = document.getElementById("fragment");

    if(myNameSpace==""||myUserName==""||myPassword=="")
    {
        myFrag.innerHTML="";
        myFrag.innerHTML= "<HTML><BODY><b>Please enter Authentication information ....</b></BODY></HTML>";
        return;
    }

    if(myReportID=="")
    {
        myFrag.innerHTML="";
        myFrag.innerHTML= "<HTML><BODY><b>Please enter the Report ID ....</b></BODY></HTML>";
        return;
    }

    var url = parent.settings.document.getElementById("serverURL").value + "/bi/v1/disp/rds/pagedReportData/report/" + document.getElementById("storeID").value;
    window.status = "Loading Report. Please wait....";
    var frag = document.getElementById("fragment");
    frag.innerHTML= "<HTML><BODY>Loading Report. Please wait....</BODY></HTML>";
    try
    {
        objXHR.open("GET", url, true);
        objXHR.onreadystatechange = callBack;
        objXHR.send(null);
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        alert("Error occurs when doing report.\r\n"+ e);
    }

 }

function doLogon()
{

    var xmlData =
      "xmlData=<auth:credentials xmlns:auth='http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/ccs/auth/types/1'>"
      +"<auth:credentialElements><auth:name>CAMNamespace</auth:name>"
      +"<auth:value><auth:actualValue>"+myNameSpace+"</auth:actualValue></auth:value></auth:credentialElements>"
      +"<auth:credentialElements><auth:name>CAMUsername</auth:name>"
      +"<auth:value><auth:actualValue>"+myUserName+"</auth:actualValue></auth:value></auth:credentialElements>"
      +"<auth:credentialElements><auth:name>CAMPassword</auth:name>"
      +"<auth:value><auth:actualValue>"+myPassword+"</auth:actualValue></auth:value></auth:credentialElements>"
      +"</auth:credentials>";

    try
    {

        var url = parent.settings.document.getElementById("serverURL").value + "/bi/v1/disp/rds/auth/logon";
        objXHR.open("POST", url, false);
        objXHR.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        objXHR.setRequestHeader("Content-length",xmlData.length);
        objXHR.setRequestHeader("Connection","close");
        objXHR.send(xmlData);

        if(objXHR.status == 200)
        {

            // Processes the response from the CMS Authentication service.
            // If we recieve an "accountInfo" element back, we have successfully logged in.
            var accountInfo = objXHR.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("auth:accountInfo");

            if (accountInfo.length > 0)
            {   
                objXHR = new XMLHttpRequest(); //each request can only be opened once
                doReport();
            }
            else
            {
                //Otherwise, prompt error message
                alert("Error occurs when doing logon. Please check input credentials.");
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var url =  parent.settings.document.getElementById("serverURL").value + "/bi/v1/disp/rds/auth/logon";   
            alert(url);
            showError(objXHR.responseText);
            window.status = "Done";
        }
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        alert("Error occurs when doing logon.\r\n"+e);
    }

}

function showError(msg)
{
    var frag = document.getElementById("fragment");
    frag.innerHTML= "Complete";
    frag.style.visibility = "hidden";
    frag = document.getElementById("error")
    frag.innerHTML= msg;
    frag.style.visibility = "visible";
}

function doLogoff()
{
    try
    {
        objXHR.open("POST", parent.settings.document.getElementById("serverURL").value + "/bi/v1/disp/rds/auth/logoff", false);
        objXHR.send(null);
        checkLogoffStatus();
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        alert("Error occurs when doing logoff.\r\n"+e);
    }
}

function checkLogoffStatus()
{
    if(objXHR.readyState == 4 && objXHR.status == 200)
    {
        window.status = "Successfully log off IBM Cognos Service.";
        alert("Successfully log off IBM Cognos Service.");
    }
    else
    {
        var frag = document.getElementById("fragment");
        frag.innerHTML = objXHR.responseText;
        alert("HTTP ERROR " + objXHR.status + ": " + objXHR.statusText);
        window.status = "Done";
    }
}   

function callBack()
{
    if (objXHR.readyState == 4)
    {

        if (objXHR.status == 200)
        {
            var frag = document.getElementById("fragment");
            frag.innerHTML = objXHR.responseText;
            window.status = "Done";

        }
        else if (objXHR.status == 403)
        {
            doLogon();
        }
        else
        {
            alert("CALLBACK HTTP ERROR " + objXHR.status);
            window.status = "Done";
        }
    }
}


</script>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif; font-weight: normal"><br />
<table align="center" width="95%"
    style="border-bottom-style: solid; border-top-style: solid; border-left-color: #004080; border-top-color: #004080; border-right-color: #004080; border-left-style: solid; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-color: #004080; border-bottom-width: thin; border-right-width: thin; border-left-width: thin; border-top-width: thin">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td
                style="text-align: center; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bold; background-color: #0080C0">CMS
            Authentication Sample</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table width="100%">
          <td align="left" width="60%">
            Name Space:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" size="40", id="nameSpace" value="PLACEHOLDER"><br><br>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;User Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" size="40", id="userName" value="PLACEHOLDER"><br><br>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Password:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="password" size="40", id="password" value="PLACEHOLDER"><br><br>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Report ID:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input size="40" id="storeID" value="PLACEHOLDER"><br><br>
          </td>
          <td align="left" width="40%">
            <input type="submit" value="Report Output" onClick="doReport()"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" id="logoff" value="Logoff from IBM Cognos Server" onclick="doLogoff()"><br>
          </td>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td
        style="border-top-style: dashed; border-top-color: #000000; border-top-width: medium; border-bottom-style: dashed; border-bottom-width: medium; border-bottom-color: #000000"
            height="100%">
        <DIV id="fragment" style="height: 100%; width: 100%">Your report will appear here</DIV>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure about the infinite loop but you may be missing a `objXHR.withCredentials = true;` in your `doReport` function.

Comment: @tdcc Where should that go exactly?

Comment: Before `objXHR.send(null);`. Also, when debugging, where/when is the infinite loop happening?

Comment: If you add the `objXHR.withCredentials = true;`, then you must also add the following to your httpd.conf file: `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"` in addition to adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header

Comment: Can you supply a full list of request & response headers - that would certainly be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

Cause Configuration of Browsers and Webservers is not allowing CORS requests.

This problem happens by modern design of the Browsers and Webservers, not related to IBM Cognos product.

This can be fixed by moving the requested resource to the same domain or by enabling CORS = Cross Origin Resource Sharing in Webserver and Browser IE / IIS has this enabled in the Browser / Webserver chain, if this is working there.

See : http://enable-cors.org for more information for both Servers and Clients.

For Browsers check the Browser Support sites, as this very likely could be an internal setting.

General information on CORS :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

reference: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21698830